# DefaultMessageListenerContainer Not Reading Messages from IBM MQ

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am trying to create some Spring Boot code that uses DefaultMessageListenerContainer to listen to messages from IBM MQ.

I can create the MQQueueConnectionFactory and send and receive messages using JmsTemplate but this is intended to by high throughput and want use a listener instead of polling.

I have consolidate much of the code down to a Component so I hope I have all that is relevant.

If I schedule the receiveMessage method, it picks up queued messages so I know the sendMessage method is queuing messages.

```
@Component
class AllInOneTest {

    private MessagingConfiguration.QueueConfig config;
    private MQQueueConnectionFactory           connectionFactory;
    private JmsTemplate                        jmsTemplate;
    private DefaultMessageListenerContainer    listenerContainer;
    private final Logger                       logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public AllInOneTest(MessagingManager manager) throws JMSException {
        String detailsName = "default";
        config = manager.getMessagingDetails(detailsName).getConfig();

        logger.debug("AllInOneTest Initializing Connection Factory: {}", detailsName);
        connectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHostName(config.getHost());
        connectionFactory.setPort(config.getPort());
        connectionFactory.setTransportType(config.getTransportType());
        connectionFactory.setQueueManager(config.getQueueManager());
        connectionFactory.setChannel(config.getChannel());

        logger.debug("AllInOneTest Initializing Message Listener: {}", detailsName);
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultListener = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        defaultListener.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

        defaultListener.setExceptionListener((ee) -> {
            logger.warn(String.format("AllInOneTest Message Listener Error: %s", detailsName), ee);
        });

        defaultListener.setDestinationResolver((session, name, pubSub) -> {
            Destination ret = session.createQueue(name);

            logger.debug("AllInOneTest Created Listener Destination: {}", ret);

            return ret;
        });

        defaultListener.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
                logger.info("AllInOneTest Listening For Message: {}", message);
            }
        });

        // TODO Configure subscription.
        // defaultListener.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
        // defaultListener.setSubscriptionName("masher-service");

        // TODO Configure concurrency.
        // defaultListener.setConcurrency(config.getConcurrency());

        // TODO Configure transaction.
        // defaultListener.setSessionTransacted(config.getAcknowledgeMode() == Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        listenerContainer = defaultListener;

        logger.debug("AllInOneTest Initializing JMS Template: {}", detailsName);
        jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
        jmsTemplate.setMessageConverter(new SpringToJMSMessageConverter());
        jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(1000L);
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(config.getOutputQueue());
        jmsTemplate.setDestinationResolver((session, name, pubSub) -> {
            Destination ret = session.createQueue(name);

            logger.debug("AllInOneTest Created JMS Template Destination: {}", ret);

            return ret;
        });

        listenerContainer.setDestinationName(config.getOutputQueue());

        logger.debug("AllInOneTest Starting Message Listener: {} on {}", detailsName, config.getOutputQueue());
        listenerContainer.start();
    }

    // @Scheduled(fixedRate = 500L)
    public void receiveMessage() {
        Object message = jmsTemplate.receiveAndConvert();
        if (message != null) {
            logger.info("AllInOneTest Received: {}", message);
        }
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1500L)
    public void sendMessage() {
        int count = counter.incrementAndGet();
        org.springframework.messaging.Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(String.format("JMS Masher Message %d %s %s", count,
                new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date()), UUID.randomUUID().toString())).build();

        logger.info("AllInOneTest Sending: {} [{}]", message.getPayload(), message.getHeaders());

        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(config.getInputQueue(), message);
    }

}
```

I am calling DefaultMessageListenerContainer.start() but I get the sense it is not "starting" and I must be missing something.

The DestinationResolver is called for the JmsTemplate but not the DefaultMessageListenerContainer.

I don't see any exceptions in the console.

Thanks for any help,
Wes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultListener = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();

When you create the container programmatically, rather than having Spring manage it as a `@Bean`, you have to call `afterPropertiesSet()` (after you have set all the properties, and before you `start()` it).

This is true for many Spring components. It's generally better to let Spring manage them.

Comment: Ahhh. I had see that in some unrelated samples. I have a `@Bean` and `@JmsListener` implementation working but I may have a requirement that I need to configure one or more listeners based on configuration. I am using Spring so I don't need to write procedural code but requirements don't always behave. Thanks.

Comment: That's fine, understood; but whenever instantiating Spring-provided components yourself, you should always check if they implement `InitializingBean` and, if they do, call `afterPropertiesSet()`.