# Why ActiveMQ Artemis auto delete address if all listeners are destroyed?

Tags: java, jms, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

We are develop a micro-service system that use ActiveMQ Artemis as the communication method between service. Since the requirement ask to be able to stop the listeners at runtime, we can not use `@JmsListener` provide by spring-artemis. After digging the internet and finding out that spring use `MessageListenerContainer` behind the scence, we come up with the idea of maintain a list of `MessageListenerContainer` our self.

```java
    @Bean(name = "commandJmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory commandJmsListenerContainerFactory(
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        var factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        factory.setPubSubDomain(false);
        return factory;
    }

    // Use
    private Map<String, DefaultMessageListenerContainer> commandQueue;

    public void subscribeToCommandQueue(String queueName, CommandListener<?> command) {
        commandQueue.computeIfAbsent(queueName, key -> {
            var endPoint = new SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint();
            endPoint.setDestination(queueName);
            endPoint.setMessageListener(message -> {
                try {
                    var body = message.getBody(String.class);
                    command.execute(commandMessageConverter.deserialize(body));
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Error while process message for queue: " + queueName, e);
                }
            });
            var container = commandJmsListenerContainerFactory.createListenerContainer(endPoint);
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44555106/defaultmessagelistenercontainer-not-reading-messages-from-ibm-mq
            // for Every object of Spring classes that implement InitializingBean created manually, we need to call afterPropertiesSet to make the object "work"
            container.afterPropertiesSet();
            container.start();
            return container;
        });
    }

    public void start() {
        commandQueue = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    public void stop() {
        commandQueue.values().forEach(DefaultMessageListenerContainer::destroy);
        commandQueue.clear();
    }
```

While testing, I notice that after we destroy all the listener by calling `stop()` , the queue and the address in the Artemis console are deleted too. It isn't the case for durable subscription.

```java
    @Bean(name = "eventJmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory eventJmsListenerContainerFactory(
        CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory,
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        cachingConnectionFactory.setClientId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        var factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, cachingConnectionFactory);
        factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
        factory.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
        return factory;
    }

    // usage is the same as the first block code, except we store multicast subscriptions in another map
    private Map<String, DefaultMessageListenerContainer> eventTopic;
```

After running the unit tests and destroying all the listeners of two maps, only the `test-event-topic` address and its queues were kept, the `test-command-queue` was deleted. Why both the queues behave differently?

[image]

Also, what is the correct behavior? We afraid the auto deletion will remove messages that aren't sent in the queue yet. On the other hand, new queue under `test-event-topic` keep being created if we run the test again and again. I think it is because of the line `cachingConnectionFactory.setClientId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());` . But for durable subscription, not setting clientId result in error.

The connection factory used in the app is an `CachingConnectionFactory`  created by spring-artemis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the broker will auto-create addresses and queues as required when a message is sent or a consumer is created by the core JMS client. These resources will also be auto-deleted by default when they're no longer needed (i.e. when a queue has no consumers and messages or when an address no longer has any queues bound to it). This is controlled by these settings in `broker.xml` which are discussed in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html#configuring-addresses-and-queues-via-address-settings):

- `auto-create-queues`
- `auto-delete-queues`
- `auto-create-addresses`
- `auto-delete-addresses`

To be clear, auto-deletion should not cause any message loss by default as queues should only be deleted when they have 0 consumers and 0 messages. However, you can always set auto-deletion to `false` to be 100% safe.

Queues representing durable JMS topic subscriptions won't be deleted as they are meant to stay and gather messages while the consumer is offline. In other words, a durable topic subscription will remain if the client using the subscription is shutdown without first explicitly removing the subscription. That's the whole point of durable subscriptions - they are *durable*. Any client can use a durable topic subscription if it connects with the same client ID and uses the same subscription name. However, unless the durable subscription is a "shared" durable subscription then only one client at a time can be connected to it. Shared durable topic subscriptions were added in JMS 2.0.

Comment: So the durable topic queue still be there even if the instance of the service that hold the client is shutdown, killed or restarted? I don't think any other newly created instance of the same or other services can reuse the topic queue, so durable topic queue may not be the option for our use case.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. Hope that helps!

Comment: In case I enable share subscriptions, the client Id should be some thing that is not random (e.g the service name) right? So multiple instance can share the topic queue.

Comment: Correct. The client ID can't be random for each consumer. They all have to use the same client ID. Technically speaking, the client ID can actually be `null` for each consumer and as long as they use the same subscription name they should share the same subscription.

Comment: I don't know why but when I start two instance of the same spring boot jar. One instance complaint that the client id (spring app name in my case) is being used by other connection from the other instance. I end up leave the client id to null and set the subscription name to app name + topic name to make sure all instances of the same service share the same queue. Isn't that client id can be shared with shared subscription in JMS 2.0?

Comment: I believe you need to do something in Spring to explicitly configure it to be shared otherwise it won't use the new JMS 2.0 API methods to create the shared subscription and you'll get the old behavior where subscriptions can't be shared and you get an exception if you try to share them. If you need additional help here I recommend you create a new question rather than continuing to go back and forth in the comments here.